# How to check if Skype call is connected or disconnected in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, skype

This code call successfully but doesn't able to track if call is still ongoing or not.

```
import webbrowser

def call_number(number):
try:
    print(f"Calling number: {number}")

    # Generate Skype URI for the number
    skype_uri = f"skype:{number}?call"

    # Open the Skype URI in a new tab of the default web browser
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(skype_uri)

    #.... Logic to check if skype call is connected or not.

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error calling number: {number}")
    print(str(e))

call_number('skype.test.user.1')
```

Comment: Where does `webbrowser` come from?

Comment: import webbrowser. Have modified the code.

Comment: Based on [its docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html), it doesn't have any more capability that opening links in a browser. If you want more control than that, you should look at selenium. Note that it's a bit of a learning curve.

Comment: @Ouroborus Can you please give a reproducible solution ? I am not able to do it.

Comment: You're expected to put in effort, we're not going to just do it for you, there are a ton of tutorials out there on the topic. Make an attempt, with the associated time and research, then, if you encounter some specific problem that more research and effort isn't solving, come back and post another question asking about the specific problem.

Comment: Give one link. I tried out almost 10 different ways via microphone connection, process running etc. Nothing works.